# Movement of charged particles in gasses or vacuum

Tags: basic

Electrical current can be formed inside gasses and even inside vacuum under certain conditions. The charged particles that form the current there are positively and negatively charged ions and electrons. To move the charged particles there has to be an electrical field that will act with an mechanical force upon them.

The question I have is whether charged particles move along and on lines of vector of electrical field **inside gasses and vacuum**.

From my understanding, electrons after acted on upon a force move in the direction of electrical field but in an opposing way. Since the force is tangent to lines of electrical field in every point, my conclusion is that charged particles do move along the lines of the field. But is it generally true for every case?

Comment: The charged particles are *accelerated* by the force applied. As per the basic mechanics, they move in the direction of the *initial* velocity plus the velocity acquired due to this acceleration.

Comment: And in gases they will be scattering a lot.

Comment: So in *average* they will move along the lines of the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Charged particles do not move along electric field lines. They feel a force along electric field lines, which accelerates them tangent to the line as you said, but now they have momentum and will not stay on the line if the line curves away from them.

There are some cases where particles will stay on electric field lines - if the lines are straight and the particles start with zero velocity, or velocity that is already tangent to the lines. In most cases they do not.

Comment: Electrons will move tangentially to equipotential lines I think you mean (assuming two plates and one plate has electrons liberated from it).

Comment: @Andyaka are you thinking of perpendicularly? Tangentially means in the same direction as the lines. Or are you confusing electric field lines and equipotential lines? Or are you confusing electric field lines with magnetic field lines?

Comment: There is no force tangent to equipotential lines. Force is between two different potentials.

Comment: I might be getting mixed up between tangentially and perpendicularly? Yeah ignore my dumb comment.

Answer (score 1):

An electron feels a force from the electric field F=qE, so in a vacuum (assuming there is no magnetic field) the electron will feel a force from the electric field. This is commonly used in CRT's and vaccum tubes to transfer electrons.

In a gas it's different, the electron will move from the same force from the electric field but it will also feel local forces from ions and other atoms. It might also bump into or recombine with ions. So the path would probably follow a brownian motion path, but it's average path would look like it was moving in the direction of the electric field.

The interesting thing is ions would be positive so they will move in the opposite direction of electrons. This happens in space with plasmas (above the earth and other places)